# Does QFile::copy keep the source file permissions in the copied file?

Tags: c++, qt, permissions, copy, qfile

I am trying to copy a game from a disk or USB flash drive to hard drive in my computer using Qt and I wanted to use `QFile::copy` and it is important for me to keep the permissions like being executable and writable.

Do I have to use `QFile::setPermissions` or the permissions are not changed by default in the copy function call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`QFile::copy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#copy) preserves the file permissions, as evidenced by the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfile.cpp.html#_ZN5QFile4copyERK7QString):

```
if(!error) {
    QFile::setPermissions(newName, permissions());
    close();
    unsetError();
    return true;
}
```

`QFile::setPermissions(newName, permissions());` actually copies the permissions from the current file to the file named `newName`. Hence, there is no need to do that manually.